# Difference between 'var foo = function ...' and 'function foo() ...'

Tags: javascript, syntax

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“Usual” functions vs function variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333830/usual-functions-vs-function-variables-in-javascript)
>   [What do you call this JavaScript syntax, so I can research it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208236/what-do-you-call-this-javascript-syntax-so-i-can-research-it)

Is there a fundamental difference between

```
function foo()
{
    things();
}
```

and

```
var foo = function()
{
    things();
}
```

Or is `function ...` just syntactical sugar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are different (but produce similar results). Basically, the first is an actual named function. The second is a regular variable declaration with an anonymous function attached to it. There are some subtle differences...they are summed up nicely here:

[JavaScript Function Declaration Ambiguity](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-function-declaration-ambiguity/) (Be sure to read the comments too...more good info there)

Comment: FYI, looks like the author got rid of the comments on that post. Still worth a read though.

Comment: var foo = function(){} is just VARIABLE DEFINING, before defining will be undefined.function foo(){} is regular function declaration, if before declare use it,the JavaScript interpreter will find it even if they aren't declared until further parts in your code.

Comment: @Eric Andres, Seems like the author got rid of the website/domain too ;)