# how to restore overriden javascript print method

Tags: javascript

My previous colleague rewrite window.print method:

```
function print(data){

    var window_print = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=768, width=1024');

    window_print.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Печать</title></head><body>' + data + '</body></html>');

    window_print.print();
    window_print.close();
}
```

My intention was to use default behavior of that function: just print current page, and I added:

> if(data) {....} else { window.print() }

And of course I received error: "too much recursion: window.print();"

My question is how to invoke default behavior window.print()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Ok, it appears that `print` is an own property of `window` in some browsers, and isn't in others. Therefore, just cache the value of `window.print`:

```
var printWindow = window.print;

// define your new print function here
var print = function(data) { ... };

// then later:
printWindow.call(window);
```

NB: If you're doing all this in the global scope, then you'll need to define the new `print` using a function expression (`var print = ...`) rather than a function declaration (`function print(data) { ... }`) because function declarations get hoisted to the top of their scope, and therefore the `print` redefinition would happen before you had chance to cache it. If you're not doing it in the global scope, then it doesn't matter as the new `print` won't override `window.print` regardless of how it's defined.

**Original**:

Try:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(window).print.call(window);
```

`print` doesn't appear to be an own property of `window`, meaning that the newly defined `print` merely shadows something further up the prototype chain. You can bypass this shadowing by moving up the prototype chain using `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

You'll also need to use `call` so that the `print` method receives the correct value for `this`.

Comment: @yonishepelev ah, it appears like `print` is an own property of window in `firefox`. Looks like you'll have to cache the value of `print` before defining the new value, and use the cached reference.

Comment: @BYossarian unfortunately your edit suffers the same as my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the original print method as another property in the window, just before the definition of your own `print()`.

**EDIT:** You also need to define the new `print` function specifically as `window.print = function(){...}` rather than `function print(){...}` in order to be able to access the original - see answers with nice links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208994/1901857) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314482/1901857). This won't have any impact on how you call the method.

```js
window.originalPrint = window.print;

window.print = function(data)
{
    if(data)
    {
        document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = data;
    }
    else
    {
        window.originalPrint();
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>

<button onclick="window.print('hello')">print('hello')</button>
<button onclick="window.print()">print()</button>
```

Comment: ok I worked out what's going on, and learnt something myself :) and updated my answer